# tf.train.Features TypeError: No positional arguments allowed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I may be doing something silly here, but I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

This code works:

```
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
      'image/height': _int64_feature(FLAGS.img_height),
      'image/width': _int64_feature(FLAGS.img_width),
      'image/colorspace': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(colorspace)),
      'image/channels': _int64_feature(channels),
      'image/format': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(image_format)),
      'image/label': _bytes_feature(label_img_buffer),
      'image/label_path': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(os.path.basename(lbl_path))),
      'image/fn_0': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(os.path.basename(ex_paths[0]))),
      'image/encoded_0': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(ex_image_buffers[0])),
      'image/fn_1': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(os.path.basename(ex_paths[1]))),
      'image/encoded_1': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(ex_image_buffers[1])),
      'image/fn_2': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(os.path.basename(ex_paths[2]))),
      'image/encoded_2': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(ex_image_buffers[2]))}))
return example
```

But this code does not work (throws the TypeError in the post title):

```
feature_dict={
      'image/height': _int64_feature(FLAGS.img_height),
      'image/width': _int64_feature(FLAGS.img_width),
      'image/colorspace': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(colorspace)),
      'image/channels': _int64_feature(channels),
      'image/format': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(image_format)),
      'image/label': _bytes_feature(label_img_buffer),
      'image/label_path': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(os.path.basename(lbl_path))),
      }

  for idx, image in sorted(ex_image_buffers.iteritems()):
    img_key = 'image/encoded_' + str(idx)
    fn_key = 'image/fn_' + str(idx)
    feature_dict[img_key] = _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(image))
    feature_dict[fn_key] = _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(os.path.basename(ex_paths[idx])))

  example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature_dict))
  return example
```

ex_image_buffers is a list.

As far as I can tell, tf.train.Features takes a dictionary as an argument, and I'm assembling the same dictionary (I think) in the first example and the second. The second allows me to adjust the dictionary based on some other code, so I'd prefer to avoid hard-coding the different fields.

Ideas? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, I think you have a silly mistake.  Try

`example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature_dict))`

as the error states, tf.train.Features requires you to pass by keyword/argument pairs.  You need to add keyword `feature` as was done in the first example you provided.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Appreciate the help. Why would this requirement be here?

Comment: I did not design the API so I can't say.  You are using the constructor of the class and the documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Features) shows only `**kwargs` as input.

Comment: @JimParker that link to documentation you provided has absolutely nothing. Is there a way to know about what these methods do, because the documentation is mostly a list of all the methods.

Comment: @deadcode: Um, that webpage has been changed (Jan 2018)...don't see old info.  Best try following links to the definitions.